# What is the suitable name of this phobia?

Tags: single-word-requests

A guy who is living with fear about future girlfriend or wife may leave him if she finds a man better than him in all possible ways.

What is the suitable name of this phobia?

Comment: Not a phobia, that's life, buddy. [Possible mitigation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGNWVwTq0cQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a specific form of [**pistanthrophobia**](https://exploringyourmind.com/pistanthrophobia-afraid-to-trust-others/):

> Pistanthrophobia is characterized by an irrational fear of building an
>   intimate and personal relationship with others. Past trauma or harmful
>   experiences carry so much weight that fear overcomes the desire to
>   trust others.
>
> People with this condition begin to feel as if everyone sooner or
>   later will disappoint or betray them. They become extremely
>   distrustful. They’re afraid of the idea that past harms may be
>   repeated and they don’t want to let that happen.

In your example, the person would fear their partner betraying them for somebody else.

Comment: I haven't been able to find this word in OED, Cambridge or Merriam Webster. The link is not to a dictionary but to a website which does not declare what it is or who is behind it.

Comment: @NigelJ Google the word. You'll find many other links. It doesn't seem formally lexicographical yet, but it's referenced in enough places to have some kind of cultural use. (Including a submission to Merriam-Webster: http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_alpha.php?letter=Pi&last=90)

Comment: A submission  by a single individual is not an established reference. This could be just a word made up by an unauthorised website making money out of peddling pseudo-psychology (for all I know).

Comment: 'It doesn't seem formally lexicographical yet' looks like 'It's not in the English lexicon' to me, which makes the answer unreliable at best. And at best a comment.

Comment: @NigelJ here's another writer (in 2015) who endorses the [word](https://thoughtcatalog.com/s-j-catherine/2015/03/pistanthrophobia-the-fear-of-trust-yes-its-an-actual-phobia/) but... here's a dictionary entry! https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pistanthrophobia  Hooray! (oops not yet approved)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth there seems to be over 500 results attested by [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=pistanthrophobia&num=20&tbm=bks&ei=Z3MBW_hPqoaPBKmQnLAJ&start=40&sa=N&biw=1316&bih=660&dpr=1.1) which use the term.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The answer should contain this. But the lack of validation by any dictionary supports 'It doesn't seem formally lexicographical yet' and ' 'It's not in the English lexicon ... makes the answer unreliable at best. And at best a comment.'

Comment: I am ironically reminded of the times I've objected to somebody else calling something a word when it's not in a dictionary—and then being pilloried with the argument that dictionaries don't include all words and that you can't prove a negative. Suddenly, those positions have simply switched. It's a good thing I wasn't trying to defend the word *levidrome* . . . ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like insecurity. But there is [autophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophobia) also known as monophobia, isolophobia, or eremophobia: the specific phobia of isolation; a morbid fear of being egotistical, or a dread of being alone or isolated.